# Magento 1 to Magento 2 conersion Mage::getModel('sales/order')

Tags: magento2, conversion

What is the class that is instantiated with command `Mage::getModel('sales/order')` in Magento 1 and what is the replacement of this class in Magento 2, ie. how can I get it with command `$objectManager -> get($stringForGettingIt)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mage::getModel('sales/order')` is instantiated from

> class Mage_Sales_Model_Order

You can achieve this in magento 2 from below code.

```
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this but it is showing fatal error Area code is not set . can you tell me how to deal with it?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Area code is not set in /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:152 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(173): Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode() #1 /var/www/html/magento22/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() #2 /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start() #3 /var/www/html/magento22/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framewor in /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 175
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load order collection , You must set the area code first.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$app_state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$model = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
$orders = $model->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
```